# MIPS exception handling (Specifically branch delay slots)

Tags: exception, mips

Say an exception has been hit in the branch delay slot of a conditional branch

e.g.

```
    BEQ a0, zero, _true
    BREAK (0000)
    sw a0, 0000(t0)
_true:
    sw a1, 0000(t0)
```

My exception handler will pick up the exception *type 9* from the *BREAK* instruction and set the *BD* bit of the *CAUSE* register to 1 as it is in the branch delay and the EPC will be the address of the branch.

The documentation says that this will require complex processing which isn't described. i.e. Getting the target of the branch/jump, doing any required comparison then setting the PC to the true or false address.

My solution to get around the complex processing (which is a bit of a hack) is as follows:

1. Store the instruction in the branch delay slot
2. NOP the instruction in the branch delay slot
3. Return from the exception handler restoring all registers
4. re-execute the *BEQ a0, zero, _true* and the branch delay will be a nop so it will have no effect
5. Place a sw breakpoint at the target(s) of the branch and set a flag
6. once the sw breakpoint is hit restore the branch delay slot and remove traces of the sw breakpoints.

Parsing branches and jumps is fine (hence why i can get the targets) but in the conditional branches, once i have parsed, i then have to do the comparisons to determine whether to jump to the true part of go to the false (next line) which i feel is more work than i would like. *Do I not??*

My problem with my hacky method is:

Will the CPU have already stored that it has hit the conditional branch and have determined that after the branch delay slot has been executed whether it is going to take the branch or not, therefore once i point the *Program Counter* back to the branch and it gets executed instead of executing correctly it thinks it must jump to the true or false part of the branch which was pre-determined before the exception occurred? (try a "double jump")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you got the MIPS programmers documents? if you want an 100% accurate answer read them - if not I can just tell you the important bits as I remember them.

in short - yes you need to load the instruction from memory, parse it and interpret the result to figure out where you have to continue. "Patching" the code as you expressed would work too, but you need to make sure the instruction cache gets invalidated, else you will be running from the cache and end in an infinite loop.

the updating of the PC follows after the delay slot has been executed, until then it will point to the branch. there is no special handling during an exception except you have a register which says if you are in a delay slot or not.
you`d need to emulate all instructions that can conditionally raise an exception in your handler (load/store) along with the branch instructions. if its another kind of instruction in the DS you just can restart at the branch (the exception was an external interrupt in this case).

if your concern is about performance then simply dont put exception-raising instructions in a delay slot.

edit: and no, MIPS stores nothing about interrupted instructions, but the method you are suggesting likely will be slower due to having to invalidate the ICache twice

Comment: thank you! Are there any good docs on the more advanced exception handling, i can only find ones on simple "add 4 to the epc" docs. And at the minute i'm not too bothered about speed in this instance as it is for instruction stepping with software breakpoints.